Elastic index option doesn't accept int4_hnsw
I want to create a dense vector index with int4_hnsw option as said in document (Automatically quantize vectors for kNN search) but after running the same example i got this error:
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown vector index options type [int4_hnsw] for field [my_vector]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping: Unknown vector index options type [int4_hnsw] for field [my_vector]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Unknown vector index options type [int4_hnsw] for field [my_vector]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}

but int8_hnsw is acceptable!
does anybody know what should I do?
